# Using fputc() to store an integer in a file changes the integer format

Tags: c, file, ascii

i am quite new to C and i am trying to use fputc() to store an integer in a file.  The function works when I look at the file the Integers are in a different format.

For Example:

1) `fputc(ppm1->max, file1);`

`ppm1->max` points to an Integer value of 255 but when I look at the file it comes up as 'ÿ'.

2)

```
fputc((char)ppm1->width, file1);
fputc(' ',file1);
fputc(ppm1->height, file1);
```

`ppm1->width` and `ppm1->height` point to 20 and 16 respectively, but when in the file they show as DC4 DLE.

Comment: You're just looking at the (extended) [ASCII equivalents](http://ascii.cl) of the 8 bit values - the underlying raw binary value is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the character representation of the integer value (converted to `unsigned int`).

For the extended [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/), a decimal value of `255` represents `ÿ` and that is what is written to file.

That said, in case of `fputc((char)ppm1->width, file1);`, the cast is unnecessary, as `fputc()` takes an `int` as the first argument. Also, integer value of 20 and 16 refers to non-printable ASCII, so in ASCII mode, you may not see any meaningful output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fprintf()` to write int to your file
e.g

`fprintf(/*filePointer*/,"%s %s %s %d","Write","an","integer",12);`

Hope this helps :)